# Audio control is not evenly distributed on android

Tags: android, audio

I am changing audio volume by using following code but the volume is not evenly distributed. For ex: when my volume control is showing volume of 50% the output volume was not 50% of total volume and if my control show 80% volume, the actual volume was about 50% of volume.

```
'audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME);'
```